# Cant Create Automapper custom value resolver

Tags: automapper

I have been trying to create a automapper Custom value resolvers, but I seem to have missed some set up step as it can never seem to find

```
 public abstract class ValueResolver<TSource, TDestination> : IValueResolver
```

So in the following snippet will not compile.

```
using DITest.Models; // This is where the SalesOrder class is
using AutoMapper;

namespace DITest.AutoMapper.SaleOrder
{
  public class FullAddress : ValueResolver<SalesOrder, string>
  {
    protected override string ResolveCore(SalesOrder source)
    {
        return "foo bar"; 
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error message

The type or namespace name 'ValueResolver<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Its say the using AutoMapper is not used.

In the past I have been naughty and hacked in a reference for lib\net45\AutoMapper.dll

Comment: Hi there, did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please try `IMemberValueResolver` type instead of `IValueResolver`. The AutoMapper had some upgraded things.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide

Answer (score 1):

`ValueResolver` is gone. `IValueResolver` is the replacement. And there is also `IMemberValueResolver`, as the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#value-resolvers) say.